# Como fazer essa rotina em assembly mostrar 3 digitos na tela?

Tags: arduino, assembly

Tenho o seguinte código em avr assembly. [link](https://pastebin.com/wJw2TVry)

O professor passou esse código e pediu pra gente fazer o programa mostrar um resultado de 3 dígitos na tela do lcd, já que agora ele aceita somente 2. A rotina é essa:

```
converte_ascii_2d:  ld temp, -X
                    mov temp2, temp
                    clr temp3
```

Poderiam me dar uma dica de como fazer isso?